# boost lockfree queue performance issue calling boost::lockfree::queue push(), pop(), empty() functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have 2 boost::lockfree queues. One for request handling and another one for response handling.

```
typedef boost::lockfree::queue<Request*> RequestsQueue;
typedef boost::lockfree::queue<Response*> ResponseQueue;
```

I have 2 threads - "SendRequest" and "ProcessResponse" which read lockfree queues above.

RequestsQueue is populated (RequestsQueue::push()) the time program starts and depending upon how server is responding to previous requests, subsequent requests are sent in batches.

```
void SendRequest()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Request* reqPtr;

            while(RequestsQueue.pop(reqPtr))
            {
                //Send request to server
```

> 

```
void ProcessResponse()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Response* resPtr;

            while(ResponseQueue.pop(resPtr))
            {
                //Process response from server
```

Everything is working fine except CPU utilization is very high, goes upto 99%.

Code::Blocks Gprofiler tells me the problem is with pop(), empty()(not in code above, but same problem observed).
Thread is continuously executing pop() functions and it results into high CPU utilization.

I would like to know if anybody has faced performance issue using boost::lockfree queue, How did you resolve the issue.
What are alternatives to boost::lockfree queues?

I also checked boost::spsc queue, same problem there. CPU utilization is very high.

suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Do you have a wait or sleep somewhere? What you've shown is a busy loop, so of course it will take 100% cpu.

Comment: Yeah, if the queue is nearly always empty - use a 'normal' non-lockfree blocking queue, else you are just pissing away CPU cycles and memory-bandwidth.